# How to Create dataframe from existing CSV file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dataframe

I am trying to create dataframe object from an existing CSV file in python but I am facing problems. I tried to import CSV file into python but I do not know whether I succeeded or not.

```
    >>> import os
    >>> userhome = os.path.expanduser('~')
    >>> csvfile= userhome + r'\Desktop\train.csv'
    >>> with open(csvfile, "r") as f:
```

After I wrote these statements it did not do anything.

So the First problem -  Did I import CSV file to python? And if I did not how do I import?

After that how can I display data from CSV file in python?

I installed pandas

Python IDE 3.6.3 Shell

[image]

Comment: did you go through `pandas`. there is a function call read_csv which directly loads your csv to dataframe object.

Comment: I don't know if making the string a regex (using `r''`) will "fix" your use of backslashes. You normally need to use double backslash so you are escaping the escape character. ex: `'\\Desktop\\train.csv'`. I usually just get the path using unix path descriptions and handle it via `os`, like `path = os.path.abspath('/Desktop/train.csv')`.

Comment: Nothing is happening because your colon at the end is telling it that more commands are coming. Your `with` statement is saying "I want you to do something with `f`" but you never told it what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather, use pandas to read the csv:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
```

for additional options to read csv, refer to: [pandas read csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: import pandas as ps df= ps.read_csv('train.csv')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#77>", line 1, in <module>
    df= ps.read_csv('train.csv')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 655, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 405, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/pytho

Comment: I am getting multiple errors end of the trace it says FileNotFoundError: File b'train.csv' does not exist

Comment: @snowboard_maniac Sorry there was a typo. Look at my edit. Hope you installed pandas as well.

Comment: yes I have already installed it. After I executed it gives an error FileNotFoundError: File b'/Users/x\\Desktop\\train.csv' does not exist it says.Is it because of the two \\ sign? I can see the file on my desktop

Comment: @snowboard_maniac Give the full path: 'C:/Users/x/Desktop/train.csv'

Answer (score 1):

Incase anyone is interested in using the python csv package to open csv files.

```
import os, csv
some_path = os.path.expanduser('~')
csv_file = some_path + '\path_to_file_from_home_dir\file_name.csv'
# Now let's read the file
with open (csv_file,'r+') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    # Confirm that the code works by printing contents of the file 
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(', '.join(row))
```

You can read more about the [csv reader module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

to get its full capability